# Is "if __name__ == '__main__'" required in a __main__.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In a project that has a `__main__.py`, rather than

```
# __main__.py
# def main...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

...is it OK to just do:

```
# __main__.py
# def main...

main()
```

Edit:

@user2357112-supports-Monica's argument made a lot of sense to me, so I went back and tracked down the library that had been giving me issues, causing me to still be adding the `if __...` line. It's upon calling `python -m pytest --doctest-modules`.

Maybe that's the only place that makes a mistake in running `__main__.py`? And maybe that's a bug?

Reproduced by putting the first example in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) in a `__main__.py`:

```
――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― package/__main__.py ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――
package/__main__.py:58: in <module>
    args = parser.parse_args()
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/argparse.py:1755: in parse_args
    args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/argparse.py:1787: in parse_known_args
    namespace, args = self._parse_known_args(args, namespace)
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/argparse.py:2022: in _parse_known_args
    ', '.join(required_actions))
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/argparse.py:2508: in error
    self.exit(2, _('%(prog)s: error: %(message)s\n') % args)
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/argparse.py:2495: in exit
    _sys.exit(status)
E   SystemExit: 2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stderr ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
usage: pytest.py [-h] [--sum] N [N ...]
pytest.py: error: the following arguments are required: N

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Results (4.23s):
```

Comment: Before anyone says you're not supposed to actually call a file `__main__.py`: [there are in fact multiple cases where you really are supposed to call a file `__main__.py`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#interface-options).

Comment: I can't think of any good reason to add the guards within `__main__.py`, since it's a file that is intended to be run as a script.  `__name__` should always equal `"__main__"` here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's okay to skip the `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard in most regular scripts, not just `__main__.py`. The purpose of the guard is to make specific code not run if the file is imported as a module instead of run as the program's entry point, but importing a `__main__.py` as a module is usually using it wrong anyway.

Even with `multiprocessing`, you might think you need an `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard, but in the case of a `__main__.py`, it wouldn't actually help. It's commonly said that `multiprocessing` in spawn or forkserver mode imports the `__main__` script as a module, but that's a simplification of the real behavior. In particular, one part of the real behavior is that if spawn mode detects the main script was a `__main__.py`, [it just doesn't try to load the original `__main__` at all](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.2/Lib/multiprocessing/spawn.py#L241-L247):

```
# __main__.py files for packages, directories, zip archives, etc, run
# their "main only" code unconditionally, so we don't even try to
# populate anything in __main__, nor do we make any changes to
# __main__ attributes
current_main = sys.modules['__main__']
if mod_name == "__main__" or mod_name.endswith(".__main__"):
    return
```

forkserver mode also didn't load `__main__.py` when I tested it, but forkserver goes through a slightly different code path, and I'm not sure where it decided to skip `__main__.py`.

(This might be different on different Python versions - I only checked 3.8.2.)

---

That said, there's nothing *wrong* with using an `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard. Not using it has more weird edge cases than using it, and experienced readers will be more confused by its absence than its presence. Even in a `__main__.py`, I would probably still use the guard.

If you actually do want to import `__main__.py` for some reason, perhaps to unit test functions defined there, then you will need the guard. However, it might make more sense to move anything worth importing out of `__main__.py` and into another file.

Comment: What about testing packages? Would they run the file on test collection?

Comment: @Maximilian: That might depend on how you're doing test discovery. [`unittest` test discovery](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestLoader.discover) won't try to load a `__main__.py` unless you give it a weird test file pattern, for example. [pytest test discovery](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html) won't try to load a `__main__.py` either.

Comment: I tracked down a reproduction that had been haunting me and added it above

Comment: @Maximilian: It looks like `--doctest-modules` is trying to import `__main__.py` files. I didn't see anything about it in the [pytest issue tracker](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues?q=is%3Aissue+doctest-modules+__main__), so I doubt they've made an official decision one way or another whether they think this is correct behavior. It's probably worth bringing it up on the tracker.

Comment: FYI I added it as an issue to pytest: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/7124, and they responded favorably